# Having two different forms in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In my project, i have a template where i'm trying to put two forms for different use cases. I've never come across this problem before, so i don't really know where to go from here to use two forms in the same page.

At first i thought of creating another view to handle each form, but i think that this solution would create problems with the rendering of my templates, other than not being sustainable if i should have this problem again with another template.

After making some research, i found a solution but it works for class based views, but i'd like to avoid that since my view is already a function based view, and i would have to make a lot of changes in my code. However, if CBV is the best way to go, i can make the change.

Every advice is appreciated

**First field**

```
class FirstForm(forms.ModelForm):

    firstfield = forms.CharField() 
    secondfield = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("firstfield", "secondfield")
    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(FirstForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send**
```

**Second Form**

```
class SecondForm(forms.ModelForm):

    firstfield = forms.FloatField() 
    secondfield = forms.Floatfield()
    thirdfield = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModelTwo
        fields = ("firstfield", "secondfield", "thirdfield")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(SecondForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

**Template**

```
  <h3> First Form </h3>
  <form method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: red;">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>

  <h3> Second Form </h3>
  <form method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: red;">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = FirstForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            send = form.save()
            send.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = FirstForm()

    return render(request,
                  "main/mytemplate.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

I have been told to use a context in my view, but i don't know how to integrate it in my view. Is this a doable solution, or is there a better way to do this?

```
context = {
        'first_form': TradingForm(request.POST or None),
        'second_form': LimitSellForm(request.POST or None),
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what your use cases are? It is unclear in your question as to what you would like to achieve with the tow forms.

Comment: @DanielHolmes basically i'm adding another field that will be different in each of the two form. So one form will be used to trigger a certain task, the other to perform another different task

Comment: What do you mean when you say a form will trigger a certain task? Is it if a user fills in one form the view should handle it in one way, and if they fill in another form the view will handle it in another?

Comment: Yeah exactly. It should work like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. Add a `name` attribute to your buttons, like this:

```html
<button name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: red;">SUBMIT</button>
...
<button name="button2" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: red;">SUBMIT</button>
```

Then in your view, you can check which form has been submitted by looking for the button name in the post:

```py
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'button1' in request.POST:
            form1 = FirstForm(request.POST)
            if form1.is_valid():
                # do what needs to be done and redirect
        if 'button2' in request.POST:
            form2 = form = SecondForm(request.POST)
            if form2.is_valid():
                # do what needs to be done and redirect
    else:
        form1 = FirstForm()
        form2 = SecondForm()

    return render(request, "main/mytemplate.html", 
                  context={'form1': form1, 'form2': form2})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Indeed, checking from which button the form is submitted is the most effective way. One final thing: i've been making some research about class based view. Is a CBV a better solution for this specific task or are both ways equivalent?

Comment: IMO a functional based view for this use case is the most suitable, especially as it deviates from a regular type of view that has a single form. But it is possible to do it using a class based view.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I was AFK :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use TemplateView instead for normal view function and add this below

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {
        'first_form': TradingForm(request.POST or None),
        'second_form': LimitSellForm(request.POST or None),
         }
```

you can check in the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview

Comment: The OP said that they would like to avoid using a class based view